# Simple interrupt handler: request_irq returns error code -22

Tags: c, linux, module, linux-kernel, interrupt

I am writing a simple kernel module, which could register an interrupt and handle it.
However, when I try to register interrupt by calling the request_irq function,
it returns error code -22 :

> ERROR: Cannot request IRQ 30 - code -22 , EIO 5 , EINVAL 22

I believe, this error code is equal to EINVAL (invalid argument)

Please tell me, what I am doing wrong. Here is a module:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/irq.h>
#include <linux/io.h>
#include <linux/irqdomain.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/of.h>
#include <linux/of_address.h>

#include <asm/exception.h>
#include <asm/mach/irq.h>

void int068_interrupt(int irq, void *dev_id, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    printk("Interrupt should be handled there\n");
}

static int __init
clcdint_init(void)
{
    unsigned int irq;
    unsigned int irqflags;
    int ret;

    irq=68;
    irqflags=IRQF_SHARED | IRQF_NO_SUSPEND;

    ret = request_irq(irq, int068_interrupt,
            irqflags, "clcdint-int068", NULL);

    if (ret!=0) {
            printk("ERROR: Cannot request IRQ %d", irq);
            printk(" - code %d , EIO %d , EINVAL %d\n", ret, EIO, EINVAL);
    }

    printk("CLCDINT_INIT\n");
    return 0;
}

module_init(clcdint_init);

static void __exit
clcdint_exit(void)
{
    unsigned int irq;
    irq=68;
    free_irq(irq, NULL);
    printk("CLCDINT_EXIT\n");
}

module_exit(clcdint_exit);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't pass a NULL context (last parameters of the request_irq() call) when dealing with a shared interrupt line (IRQF_SHARED flag is on).

To understand why consider the following scenario: you have two identical network cards sharing the same IRQ. The same driver will pass the same interrupt handler function, the same irq number and the same description. There is no way to distinguish the two instances of the registration except via the context parameter.

Therefore, as a precaution, you can't pass a NULL context parameter if you pass the IRQF_SHARED flag.

Comment: Thank you very much! After I have changed `irqflags=IRQF_NO_SUSPEND;` , it is finally working!

Comment: Even after applying the change mentioned in the last comment, I'm still getting the same error message ("ERROR: Cannot request IRQ 68 - code -22 , EIO 5 , EINVAL 22"). Do you know what can be causing this? (btw, I'm using kernel version 2.6.32, so some of the included files doesn't exist here, perhaps this is relevant)

Comment: The problem had to do with the IRQ number. After looking at http://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/IRQnumbers.asp and changing the IRQ number to 10, instead 0f 68, everything's working.

Comment: dear gby, Currently I am trying to share my interrupt handler to a interrupt line, and changing this NULL to say 1 really worked. Thanking your very much for this. (please correct me if I am wrong!) In this case I need to disable the interrupt also in while writing the my new interrupt handler program could you please guide me how to do it.

Comment: @user1107855 the Linux kernel IRQ infrastructure normally calls your interrupt handler with the specific interrupt masked and automatically unmasks it when your handler terminates.

If you wish the IRQ to remain masked after the interrupt handler function you can call disable_irq_nosync() but please note that doing this on a shared interrupt line is probably a bad idea (you'd be blocking interrupts to all devices sharing the same line)

Answer (score -3):

`irqflags` has a type of `unsigned int`, but originally it had type `long`.

Try the following statement, it will definitely work:

`request_irq(irq, int068_interrupt,IRQF_SHARED | IRQF_NO_SUSPEND, "clcdint-int068", NULL);`