# request_irq returns -22 (-EINVAL)

Tags: c, module, linux-kernel, interrupt

The prototype of request_irq is:

```
int request_irq (   unsigned int    irq,
    irq_handler_t   handler,
    unsigned long   irqflags,
    const char *    devname,
    void *      dev_id);
```

I've noticed a similar question ["Simple interrupt handler: request_irq returns error code -22"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245626/simple-interrupt-handler-request-irq-returns-error-code-22), but I didn't use `IRQF_SHARED` flag, so there is no reason that it might conflict with dev_id being NULL. But it still fail to register test irq and the errno is always `-22(-EINVAL)`.

Here is my simple irq test module:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>

static irqreturn_t irq_handle(int irq, void *dev_id)
{
        printk("irq happened\n");
        return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
static int irq_test_init(void)
{
        int rc = request_irq(50, irq_handle, IRQF_DISABLED, "irq_test", NULL);
        if(rc!=0){
                printk(KERN_INFO "fail to register test irq, errno:%d\n",rc);
                return -1;
        }
        printk(KERN_INFO "success request irq\n");
        return 0;
}
static void irq_test_exit(void)
{
        free_irq(50, NULL);
        printk(KERN_INFO "irq module removed!\n");
        return;
}


module_init(irq_test_init);
module_exit(irq_test_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: Are you sure about irq number `50`?

Comment: Is it because of the irq number? Because after set the irq num to 10, I can register the irq successfully. The irq number 50 is not in /proc/interrupts, why can't I use it?

Comment: @LPs Actually what I want to request is irq 20, which is described in Intel Manual as "Virtualization Exception (#VE)". Is this system reserved irq number unusable by LKM?

Comment: About 50 It depends  on your platform, on my actual arm9 target I have an ecspi at interrupt 50. About interrupt 20 should be available.

Comment: @LPs I'm using a x86 platform, where can I find the available interrupt?

Comment: On CPU Reference Manual.

Comment: It seems you didn't quite understand interrupt concept on all levels: CPU, hardware (device, PIC, PIR), software (top-half, bottom-half, threading),  I would suggest to read about basics first.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko I know there should be a source to trigger the interrupt via pins, such as using INT 3 to trigger #BP. But #VE(20) is also an protected-mode exception which can be triggered by EPT violations (from Intel Manual). So why can't I register a interrupt handler for it using request_irq? Is it because there is a build-in handler for it?

Comment: `request_irq()` all about hardware interrupts. You are talking about CPU ones. They IIRC set up through CR / MSR registers.

Comment: Did this ever get resolved?  If so, please post the answer or delete the thread so we can get it off of the unanswered questions queue.